# how to install singularitygs using webpack

Tags: sass, singularitygs

I'm new to webpack and I'm trying to install singularitygs to my sass file,

I did a npm install singularitygs --save-dev

but not really sure how to go about this any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader built specifically for Webpack.

It will let you import Singularity as

```
@import "~singularitygs/stylesheets/singularitygs"
```

Tilde for `sass-loader` means "import from `node_modules`".

Comment: Thanx this worked, I just had the @import path wrong

Comment: I just open up an account it would not let me upvote because my reputation is to low, I will come back and upvote once my rep is up and lets me vote